# Replace values with nothing / null

Tags: cobol

I have a text file with delimiters (like #RT#, #LT#, #BC# etc) that need to be removed.

For example:-

Original: Taxes owed:#RT#$3000

Fixed Version: Taxes owed:$3000

Replacing with SPACES doesnt work obviously, as it puts in spaces - as this will be a computer read file - it needs to be exact - only nothing/null will do.

Any ideas?

The above is a representative sample of the data... just random paragraphs of data with #RT# and #LT# in it. Currently, a REPLACING with SPACES is used. But I need it removed entirely like in the example above. Cant post the code till tomorrow as Im on the road.

Comment: Show a representative example of your delimited data, the output you expect, the output you got with your code, and your code. As it stands all anyone can really say is "just don't include the delimiter". I also don't understand your "computer read" point, so please clarify that if there is any genuine content to it. Computers understand spaces.

Comment: What Bill said, plus "null" is not really a concept in COBOL, you need to think another way. I never tried an INSPECT MY-STRING REPLACING ALL "#RT#" BY "", but it should work. If not, an old-fashioned loop should do the trick(but it's less elegant, try the replacing first).

Comment: @gazzz0x2z INSPECT will only operate with RECPLACING and BY items being the same length.

Comment: So an old-fashioned loop.

Comment: From the sample shown, simple data-definition will do it. But, how does the sample relate to "random paragraphs"? What do the #xx# things represent? Probably UNSTRING with dummy/actual field pairs, but hard to be exact on what is shown.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for your detailed answer. However, management at my place decided at the last minute to go with spaces instead of nulls in the end...so I cant test it for veracity. I have marked your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `INSPECT yourtext REPLACING BY SPACES` leaves spaces. `INSPECT yourtext REPLACING BY ""` is not allowed (both need to be the same length or the replacing identifier be a figurative constant: SPACE[S], ZERO[S|ES], or QUOTE[S]) - a good compiler will output an understandable message if you try this.

This leaves only 3 options:

- don't use COBOL (would be the #1 option if you don't want to do anything else with the text file) but a system call, for example `sed -e 's/#RT#//g' yourfile > yourtarget`, depending on the COBOL runtime you use (it is always a good idea to add this information in the question!) you may start the process via COBOL with `CALL "SYSTEM" USING external-command`.
- `READ` the data, use an extension specific to your runtime to translate it (for example with GnuCOBOL: `MOVE FUNCTION SUBSTITUTE (yourtext, '#RT#', '', '#LT#'. '') TO translated-text`)  - may be a `FUNCTION`, a system library `CALL` - and `WRITE` the data back.
- The good old COBOL way - see below.

As the question was not about reading the data or writing it back this is only the replacing part:

Option a): **UNSTRING statement**

```
MOVE 0 TO t1, t2, t3, t4
UNSTRING yourtext
   DELIMITED BY ALL '#RT#' OR 
                ALL '#LT#' OR
                ...
             INTO target-1 COUNT IN t1
                  target-2 COUNT IN t2
                  target-3 COUNT IN t3
                  target-4 COUNT IN t4
                  ...
END-UNSTRING
MOVE SPACES TO translated-text
STRING target-1 (1:t1)
       target-2 (1:t2)
       target-2 (1:t2)
       target-2 (1:t2)
       ...
       DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO translated-text
END-STRING
```

Option b) a simple **`PERFORM VARYING`** with two pointers, combined with a simple **`IF`** statement.

```
*> you may get more performance if you `REDEFINE` source-text as a `PIC X OCCURS length-of-text TIMES` - but I find this one more better to read and it shouldn't consume much more time...

MOVE 0 TO target-pointer
PERFORM VARYING source-pointer
        FROM 1 BY 1
        UNTIL   source-pointer > length-of-text
   IF source-text (source-pointer:1) = '#'
      *> a very good optimizer would calculate the constant on the
      *> right side, you may write it directly
      IF source-pointer + 4 > length-of-text
         ADD  1 TO target-pointer
         MOVE source-text (source-pointer:)
           TO target-text (target-pointer:)
         EXIT PERFORM
      END-IF
      IF source-text (source-pointer:4) = '#RT#' OR '#LT#' OR ...
         ADD 4 TO source-pointer
         EXIT PERFORM CYCLE
      END-IF
   END-IF
   ADD  1 TO target-pointer
   MOVE source-text (source-pointer:1)
     TO target-text (target-pointer:1)
END-PERFORM
```